# How to Check the Team City version

Tags: teamcity, tfsbuild, teamcity-7.0

> How can i check the Team City version details? and which version support for project moving (move project and build configurations from one server to another server)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TeamCity version is displayed on every page (at the bottom part of it). Like this:

> TeamCity Professional 8.X.X (build XXXXXX)

Answer (score 0):

Just make this GET request to the url **/app/rest/server/version**:

https://{your.teamcity.com:8112}/app/rest/server/version

Output:

[image]